# Select channels and subtitles in AVPlayer from m3u8 playlists on tvOS swift

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer, tvos

Following the official documentation by Apple [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback_and_selection/selecting_subtitles_and_alternative_audio_tracks)

```
self.playerStatusObserver = player.observe(\.currentItem?.status, options: [.new,.old]{ (player, change) in
switch (player.status) {
   case .readyToPlay:
     player.appliesMediaSelectionCriteriaAutomatically = false
     for characteristic in player.currentItem!.asset.availableMediaCharacteristicsWithMediaSelectionOptions {
         print("\(characteristic)")

           // Retrieve the AVMediaSelectionGroup for the specified characteristic.
           if let group = player.currentItem!.asset.mediaSelectionGroup(forMediaCharacteristic: characteristic) {
               // Print its options.
               for option in group.options {
                   print("  Option: \(option.displayName)")
               }
           }
       }
```

`player.currentItem!.asset.availableMediaCharacteristicsWithMediaSelectionOptions` has no items. Tried many cases, but `player.currentItem?.tracks` has only two tracks (video and audio), even if stream has more audio tracks.

How to select audio tracks and subtitles from a `m3u8` stream, using standard `AVPlayer` and `AVFoundation` framework?

Answer (score 0):

Your code relies on the current item being ready to play to access `availableMediaCharacteristics`. It could happen that `availableMediaCharacteristics` are actually still not available at that moment unless you created the player item with the property `automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys` parameter:

```
AVPlayerItem(asset: asset, automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: ["availableMediaCharacteristicsWithMediaSelectionOptions"])
```

You can find further info about this on the following page:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1388633-automaticallyloadedassetkeys

Depending on your use case you could also prefer loading the media characteristics asynchronously, you could do this with the following code:

```
 func preloadAssetKeys() {
    let key = "availableMediaCharacteristicsWithMediaSelectionOptions"
    
    asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: [key]) {
        [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }

        var error: NSError? = nil
        switch self.asset.statusOfValue(forKey: key, error: &error) {
        case .loaded:
            // ℹ️ At this point is when availableMediaCharacteristics are actually available
            ()
        default:
            ()
        }
    }
}
```